# Please tell me how to add word limit not a character limit

Tags: jquery

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {

  var text = this.value.split(' ');
  if (text.length >= 2) {
    this.value = text[0] + ' ' + text[1];
    console.log('Word limit is 2.');
  }
});
  var text = $('.test').text().trim().split(' ');
  if (text.length >= 2) {
    $('.test').text(text[0] + ' ' + text[1]);
    console.log('Word limit is 2.');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test">Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test">is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
```

Please tell me how to add word limit not a character limit.

Like this

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing

Result: (Lorem Ipsum),(Ipsum is),(is simply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
$('.test').text(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().trim().split(' ');
  if (text.length >= 2) {
    return text[0] + ' ' + text[1];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test">Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test">is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
```

---

Comment: Please check your  Code not working Please send me live example

Comment: did you checked it running? it won't allow you to type a second space while typing.

Comment: <div class="test">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>

Result: Lorem Ipsum

Comment: @GaganDeep updated the snippet you can use that for div.

Comment: Yes i want to display first two words under the div

Comment: That is what second snippet is doing. Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks its working but i want to display text in loop( eg:- i want to display different text now i will show same text in all lines). http://homejuice.com.au/cart please check this link add something to cart

Comment: that's not the way SO is for, you should have your answer use it and if you are unable to solve it then ask another question with the tried code. Thanks.

Comment: Please check your code in my question, i am updated my question. run code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
function wordslimit(str) {
  var count=0;
  for(i=0;i<str.trim().length;i++) {
    if(str[i]==' ') 
      count++;
  }
  if(count>1)
      alert('Not more than 2 words');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/99dms78r/)

Answer (score 0):

you find your question solution in this stack overflow question and answer. find jsfiddle demo too

**[Your question solution click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693525/jquery-function-to-limit-text-entry-based-on-word-count-not-working-while-pastin)**

Comment: <script>$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {

  var text = this.value.split(' ');
  if (text.length >= 2) {
    this.value = text[0] + ' ' + text[1];
    console.log('Word limit is 2.');
  }
});
  var text = $('.test').text().trim().split(' ');
  if (text.length >= 2) {
    $('.test').text(text[0] + ' ' + text[1]);
    console.log('Word limit is 2.');
  }</script><div class="test">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test2">dummy text of the printing</div>
<div class="test">Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</div>

Comment: find fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/aVd4H/102/
I have give 20 words limit.